# perl -- check if file handle is stdin

Tags: perl, select

I am using select with a TCP server. I want to add STDIN to the select filehandle set.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use IO::Select;
use IO::Socket::INET;
my $sock = IO::Socket::INET->new(LocalPort => $serv_listen_port, Proto => 'tcp', List    en=> 1);

my $s = IO::Select->new();
$s->add(\*STDIN); #want to be responsive to user input (allow me to type commands for example)
$s->add($sock);

@readytoread=$s->can_read(1); #timeout = 1sec
foreach $readable (@readytoread) {
  if ($readable==$sock) {
    #This was a listen request, I accept and add new client here
  }
  if ($readable == STDIN){ #what to do on this line?
    #This is user typing input into server on terminal
  }
}
```

Need help with 4th to last line in the code here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$readable->fileno == fileno STDIN
```

Or, if you're comfortable with that, `fileno STDIN` is zero, which you can check directly.

Answer (score 2):

`can_read` returns the exact value passed to `add`, so you can simply use

```
$readable == \*STDIN
```

Comment: could somebody explain the usage of/story behind `\*STDIN`? Is the entire string some kind of constant? Why the backslash? is it escaping the asterisk?

Comment: @Steven Lu: STDIN is a global filehandle. Because it has no sigil, you can't just use it directly anywhere, else Perl would interpret it either as a string or as function call. The asterisk is the typeglob sigil (typeglobs can be thought of as encompassing filehandles, along with other variable types), and the backslash takes a reference to that typeglob. `IO::Select` knows it's expecting a filehandle, so it's able to dereference it as such when needed.  Check out the "Typeglobs and filehandles" section of `perldata` for a more comprehensive view of all that.